# Why doesn't my java compiler level match my installed project facet?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I made a simple Java Google AppEngine application called Guestbook in Eclipse 3.7 and am trying to run it. However, I am encountering an error that lacks a quick fix:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet.
Guestbook       Unknown Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)
```

I tried navigating to *Project | Properties* to change my project facet. However, I could not find a setting that dealt with "facet."

[image]

What does "installed Java project facet" mean, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239959/faceted-project-problem-java-version-mismatch-error-message)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can see your facets via Right click on your project->properties->Project Facets,

Here you can see my facets for an example web application:
[image: here]

I think your *Java* facet does not match with the installed one. I'm suspicious that facet is at version 1.5. Please check it.

Add-on:Open the Navigator view, expand the .settings folder, open the file org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml and manually set the Java version to 1.6.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see Project Facets anywhere under Project Properties: http://i.imgur.com/9LqSf.png I am using Eclipse 3.7 on Mac Lion. Why might this be?

Comment: I've quickly looked for similar problems and I've found some pages about it. You can check them:[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130320/how-do-i-change-the-java-version-of-my-installed-project-facet-in-eclipse), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694648/gae-getting-started-in-java-eclipse-indigo-cant-compile-as-1-6), [3](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/d04RY2fH7j0)

Comment: Thanks, I Googled around too, but all the solutions I've read hint at examining Project Properties | Facets, but I don't even have the Facets tab in the first place.

Comment: Did you read the 3rd one? _Open the Navigator view, expand the .settings folder, open the file 
org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml and manually set the 
Java version to 1.6._

Comment: There have been a couple reports of this problem from people using Google App Engine tooling. It appears that they are installing Faceted Project Framework without its corresponding UI, leaving users in the bind. Please report this issue to Google. In the meantime, GokcenG's advice of editing the specified configuration manually should unblock you.

Comment: Thank you! Solution number 3 did it. So, here's the fix I did again. 1) Switch to the Navigator Perspective (Window > Show Perspective > Navigator). 2) Open "org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml" under ".settings". 3) Changed my project facet from 1.4 to 1.6.

This problem occupied me for the past 2 hours. Thanks a lot! I hope this thread helps others who encounter the same error. How does one report issues to Google by the way?

Comment: Not sure. I'd start poking around wherever you downloaded the plugin from. See if there is a support link or something.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you solved it. At that [site](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/community) there are 3 bug tracking links but I'm not sure which one to report that problem.

Comment: works like a charm on Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0 + openJDK1.8 on CentOS 6.10 32bit platform. thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Right click on your project->properties->Project Facets,

This will show your current version of java for your project facet.

In my case I had the correct version for my facet but not my compiler,
So had to **right click on project->properties->Java Compiler**

Then under Compiler compliance level drop list and change to version of project facet.

Answer (score 10):

its simple.. in Problems infotab, rightclick on error desc and select quickfix... choose facet version upgrade..

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue in IBM RAD tool eclipse It got resolved following below.

- Right click on project
- Properties
- Project facets
- Configuration (select Default configuration for WebSphere application server v7.0 )
- Apply