# Using both jdk 1.6 and jdk 1.7 for different projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java, java-6

I am using Eclipse with JDK 1.7. My previous projects are developed in java 7 and JDK 1.7.
Now, I want to build a new project under JDK 1.6 in Eclipse. Is it possible to do that so that some projects are based on JDK 1.7 and some others are based on JDK 1.6 without conflicts?

If this can be done, please let me know how to do it step by step.

Update:
My default JDK is 1.7. I created a new project that is based on jdk1.7 by default. And then I go to the property of this project, and then java compiler, then change the compliance settings as the image shows below. But there is some error occurred. What could be the reason causes this error?

[image]

[image]

The following is the "problem" view

[image]

After some research, I have solved this problem. please see the reference about [how to fix the facet version.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387341/why-doesnt-my-java-compiler-level-match-my-installed-project-facet)

Comment: 1. Declare different JRE/JDK in eclipse 2. Add them to your project settings !

Comment: Can you add the "Problems" view, and then post the error being shown on your project ?

Comment: @CristianMeneses I have added the problem view, it said java compiler level does not match the version of the installed java project facet. I do not really know what that means and how to fix it. please help.

Comment: @CristianMeneses Oh i have figured it out. thanks for pointing me to check the problem view. This really helps me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set overall workspace properties to use one version of Java and set individual project properties to use another.

- To set overall workspace properties, click on *Window* > *Preferences*, then navigate to *Java* > *Compiler*.
- To set project properties, right-click on the project and select *Properties*. Navigate to *Java Compiler* and check "Enable project specific settings"

You can choose from among the installed JREs for either setting. To tell Eclipse about a newly installed JRE, you can open the workspace preferences and navigate to *Java* > *Installed JREs* and then click the "Add" button.

Comment: Actually I have tried this. There is some error. My default jdk is 1.7. I created a project based on 1.7 (default), then I do the same things as you described. but there is some error and I cannot find out what those errors are.

Comment: @user1387727 - Did you figure out the cause of the error(s)? Were they compilation errors or was Eclipse complaining about something else? Looking at the _Error Log_ view and/or the _Problems_ view (under _Window_ &gt; _Show View_) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done for an Eclipse Run Configuration.  You may define multiple such configurations, each of which will reference a "main class" in one of your projects.

1. In ***Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs*** define a location for each JRE/JDK.
2. For a given Eclipse project:

   - right click on the project, select ***Properties -> Java Compiler***, override and set ***compiliance level*** settings.
   - Check ***Use compliance from ...***, visit the ***Java Build Path*** and be sure you have a JRE Library set that matches the desired compliance level.
3. For a given Eclipse Run Configuration: ***Run -> Run Configurations... -> Java Application***, select an old or create a new configuration, select the ***JRE*** tab and specify the ***Runtime JRE***.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the JDK used by project under Project properties(`alt+enter`)-> Installed JREs. Also [Debug Configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_o_run_config.htm) is your friend. You can set what JDK to use when launching/running an app/program in Eclipse.