# Eclipse - Jboss Configurtioin issue

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x

I successfully integrated Jboss with Eclipse But in eclipse I am getting red cross sign on my project below is the screenshot for it.
[image: Eclipse project screenshot]

As you can see in above image I am getting red cross sign but there are no compile time errors in java files.
Below is some more information about my project.

1. Eclipse kepler
2. Jboss 7.1.1
3. Jboss runtime JRE is Jre7

Can anybody please tell where am i going wrong?

Comment: Look in the Problems view.

Comment: This red cross is only shown if you add the jboss library? I would try to open a new project and import the old one.

Comment: Problems view shows message :: java compiler level does not match the version of the installed  java project facet.

Comment: This link has solution for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387341/why-doesnt-my-java-compiler-level-match-my-installed-project-facet